# ¿Cómo mostrar una fecha guardada en MySql en un Datepicker?

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

Quiero mostrar la fecha que guardé anteriormente en la base de datos, en un `input datepicker`. Lo he intentado con la siguiente función:

`$("#datepicker").datepicker( "setDate","<?php echo $row['fecha_muestra'];" ?> );`

Pero no resulta, me muestra esta fecha "2021/12/09", que no es la que esta en la base de datos.

Comment: Y cuál es la fecha que está en la base de datos?

Comment: es fecha actual "2016-06-08"

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que estás utilizando jQuery Datepicker.

Estás usando un formato de fecha que no es el mismo que trae por defecto el Datepicker de jQuery:

> dateFormat 
>  
>   Type: String 
>   Default: "mm/dd/yy"
>   The format for parsed and displayed dates. For a full list of the possible formats see the formatDate function.

Aquí está en enlace respectivo: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

---

Tienes dos opciones:

- Cambiar el formato de fecha para que funcione con el que estás almacenando en la base de datos:

  ```
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  ```
- Cambiar el formato de la fecha antes de pasarla al datepicker (probablemente mucho más complicada que la opción anterior).